# How to do SVM Tagging in NLTK Python on Unicode Data

Tags: unicode, nltk, svm, python-3.4

Can anyone help me on how to use SVM tagging in NLTK Python.
I have the following code using TnT tagger. It works perfectly for me thereby generating the tagged output.

How to achieve the tagging with svm? 
Kindly help.. thanks

```
import nltk
import re
import time
from nltk.corpus import indian
train_data = indian.tagged_sents('konkani.pos')[:300]
from nltk.tag import tnt
l = tnt_pos_tagger = tnt.TnT()
n=tnt_pos_tagger.train(train_data)
e = open('kkn-.txt',encoding='utf-8-sig').read()
print (tnt_pos_tagger.tag(nltk.word_tokenize(e)))
```